# MSXML For Post (Classic ASP)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, msxml

I am trying to make a simple form post to a remote server using MSXML and although this should be so simple I can't figure out why it fails.  Let me explain...

CLIENT SCRIPT...

```
response.Buffer = true
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
objHTTP.open "POST","https://myurl.com/test_post_server.asp", false
    
PostData = "field1=test1&field2=test2&field3=test3"

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(PostData)
objHTTP.send PostData
strReturn = objHTTP.responseText
response.write strReturn
set objHTTP = nothing
```

REMOTE SERVER SCRIPT...

```
xResponse="No Form Data"
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    xResponse="Data Received" & "<Br>"
    CNT=0
    For Each fldName in Request.Form
        CNT=CNT+1
        xResponse = xResponse & Trim(CNT) & ": " & fldName & ": " & Request.Form(fldName) &"<br>"
    Next
end if
response.write xResponse
```

The remote server see the request as a POST because it response as follows...

Data Received

But it does not see the Form.Request object.  It should respond as follows...

```
Data Received

1: field1: test1
2: field2: test2
3: field3: test3
```

What am I doing wrong.  I use this code all the time to submit form data locally.  Does remote form submission have other requirements?

Comment: Try a simple test first just have `Response.Write Request.Form("field1")` does that come back?

Comment: You may need to URL encode your PostData prior to calling `httpRequest.Send`.  Also, the URL encoded data size should probably be used for the `Content-Length` header, as well.  And depending upon which charset the ASP server page is expecting, you may need to append something like `;charset=UTF-8` after `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for your `Content-Type`

Comment: This works for me, but not with https. Try changing `"https://myurl.com/test_post_server.asp"` to `"http://myurl.com/test_post_server.asp"` and see if it will work now.